# Socket.io hangs after 2k concurrent connections

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have purchased 2 vCPU core and 4 GB Ram memory VPS server and deployed nodejs Socket.io server. its working fine without any issue upto 2k concurrent connection. But this limit is very small according to me. when connection is reached at 3k socketio server hang and stopped working.

Normally memory usage is 300mb but after 3k connection memory usage is reaching upto 2.5 GB and not emitting packets for several seconds and after that works for very few second and server hang again.

My server is not very small for this amount of connection.

Is there any suggestion for optimisations how to increase concurrent connection without hang after few thousand clients connected simultaneously. for few clients its working fine.

Comment: Perhaps you have a memory leak in your app ? Can you post your server code ? Take a look here: https://blog.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/

Comment: @Marc I added code.